# Взятие iтого элемента строки в kotlin

Tags: строки, kotlin

Привыкший к питону человек удивился, увидев ошибку на `print(s[-1])` .  Есть ли способы взятие элемента с конца в kotlin?

Comment: [https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val s = "This is a sentence"
println(s[s.lastIndex]) // "e"
println(s[s.lastIndex - 1]) // "c"
```

Comment: ``println(s.last())``

Comment: Спасибо большое